# Should numbers be avoided in Javascript function names?

Tags: javascript

I heard from a JS developer recently that you should avoid using numbers inside function names.

For example:

```
function test1test() {
    // function body
}
```

I've never come across this before so I was wondering if it's true? If so, why?

Comment: Did he tell you why or did you ask?

Comment: Why? I used to call functions like `summonSatan666()`.

Comment: Do you have a real world example where you want to include a number? Things like `convertToMp3()` as suggested by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26865574/615754) make sense. Things like `test1()` and `test2()` where the number distinguishes between similar functions is a bad idea because the number doesn't tell you what the difference between them is.

Comment: It was through general conversation that the topic arose. I don't have an specific examples. But I had never heard of it before so I wanted to hear from the SO community whether it was actually a thing in Javascript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with having numbers in your function name, it's just a little unconventional.  The ultimate goal in function and variable naming is readability and clarity of code, so if you think including a number in your function name make the code more clear, you should make that a priority.

However, for maximum readibility and clarity in most cases, your function names should be camelCase verb phrases to follow the predominant convention.

For instance, you might want to name a function `convertToMp3()`, in which case it would be silly to instead name the function `convertToMpThree()`.  But you should avoid using names like `obj2Array()` or `format2()`, because those don't make your code more clear.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I'm going to try to answer this in without a *my-opinion* base...

Refering to [**W3's article on Javascript's best practices**](http://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices), we find the following statement, regarding to names:

> good variable and function names should be easy to understand and tell you what is going on — not more and not less. One trap to avoid is marrying values and functionality in names. A function called isLegalDrinkingAge() makes more sense than isOverEighteen() as the legal drinking age varies from country to country, and there are other things than drinking to consider that are limited by age.

Note the *not more and not less*. There's no reference on why it should matter to use or not a number in the naming of a function/variable. It is just a case of what will be easily understood when you/others read the code.

Answer (score 2):

doesnt make sense to avoid this in general..

its rather a question of style and when it actually makes sence in your context

Answer (score 2):

The only actual restriction is that you cannot start a member name with a number. Other than that, it's a matter of style. Having said that, I cannot think of a member in the standard library that has a number in it. It's certainly rare to need this, but it can be useful. No need to be too dogmatic about these kinds of things.